# PySpark: Count nested objects in array/list given condition

Tags: pyspark

How can I count elements contained in an array when a condition is met?

Consider this example:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([
    [
         ['pass', 'pass', 'fail', 'fail', 'fail'],
        ['Clear BMC SEL', 'Check SEL', 'Clear BMC SEL', 'CPU', 'Check SEL']
    ]
]),
                           ['Status', 'Description'])

+--------------------+--------------------+
|              Status|         Description|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|[pass, pass, fail...|[Clear BMC SEL, C...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

This method works well for counting a particular column, but I want to count the values that meet the condition, *given* that the corresponding value in `Status`, a separate column, is `fail`.

```
df = df.selectExpr('*', 'filter(Description, x -> x = "Clear BMC SEL"  or x = "Check SEL") as pass_array')
df = df.selectExpr('*', 'size(pass_array) as testFailCount').drop('pass_array')


# the expected result is 2
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+
|              Status|         Description|testFailCount|
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+
|[pass, pass, fail...|[Clear BMC SEL, C...|            4|
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can zip the 2 array columns using [`arrays_zip`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_zip.html#pyspark-sql-functions-arrays-zip) which creates an array of structs where the N<sup>th</sup> struct will have N<sup>th</sup> elements from the two array fields. the resulting array field can then be filtered.

here's the example.

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('desc_status_struct_arr', func.arrays_zip('description', 'status')). \
    withColumn('pass_array', 
               func.expr('filter(desc_status_struct_arr, x -> x.description in ("Clear BMC SEL", "Check SEL") and x.status = "fail")')
               ). \
    withColumn('test_fail_count', func.size('pass_array')). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+---------------+
# |status                        |description                                              |desc_status_struct_arr                                                                           |pass_array                                |test_fail_count|
# +------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+---------------+
# |[pass, pass, fail, fail, fail]|[Clear BMC SEL, Check SEL, Clear BMC SEL, CPU, Check SEL]|[{Clear BMC SEL, pass}, {Check SEL, pass}, {Clear BMC SEL, fail}, {CPU, fail}, {Check SEL, fail}]|[{Clear BMC SEL, fail}, {Check SEL, fail}]|2              |
# +------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+---------------+
```